# How to detect which UITableViewCell is at the top of a UITableView

Tags: ios

I have a view with a map and and list displayed at the same time.  I would like the map to move when the user scrolls the list.

I was hoping for something like

```
(UITableView*)tableView didScrollTableViewCellToTop:(UITableViewCell *)cell
```

I haven't found something that will support this yet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The cellForRowAtIndexPath is called whenever a cell enters the screen. You can try and do something there.

Comment: I'm sure there's something like indexPathsForVisibleCells or something. Just looking...

Comment: Yes there is . visibleCells, I combined that with scrollViewDidEndDecelerating and am pretty close to what I need.  One glitch is that what I need is the first fully visible cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the UITableView is simply a scroll-view. So you can get the offset of the scroll view and use the position to get the cell at that location:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: point];
```

To continuously monitor and change, implement a scroll-view-delegate and implement the scrollViewDidScroll method.

Comment: This was the key thanks.   I used scrollViewDidEndDecelerating  otherwise I was getting too many events.  Then I just check visibleCells and the first in the list is the cell at the top.

Answer (score 3):

You can get all the visibleCells by running...

```
NSArray *cells = [self.tableView visibleCells];
```

This returns an array of UITableViewCells.

You can then find the one with the lowest indexPath.row value to find the top one.